# Accidently deleted Registry key 'wow6432node' from 'HKLM\software'

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, recovery

I was installing/uninstalling some software and found some leftovers in the Registry, and thinking `wow6432node` was also a leftover, clicked delete. It said unable to delete and I Ignored it, but then the OS started acting strangely with messed up fonts. I can't use any software or log in, as I am dual-booting with Ubuntu and don't know how to get into Recovery.

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled then you might be able to use that to roll back to a point before you did that. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-system-restore-a5ae3ed9-07c4-fd56-45ee-096777ecd14e

Comment: Rule of thumb: unless you know precisely what a Registry key does, never delete it. While this type of issue cannot be fixed from WinRE unless there's a system restore point prior to the Registry modification _(the Registry isn't static so there's no default backup of the hives in Windows 10, however in Windows 8 they should be in `%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack`, else a Repair Install laid out in @john's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1648278/529800) will be required)_, Windows will auto-boot to WinRE upon two failed attempts of the Windows bootloader to boot Windows.

Comment: @JW0914 will '%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack' be in windows 8.1 too ? sorry for replaying late. I was into something else.

Comment: @DarkShade Yes, as the backup setting wasn't removed from the Registry until Windows 10 ~2017ish

Comment: @JW0914 "Windows will auto-boot to WinRE upon two failed attempts of the Windows bootloader to boot Windows." I can't... I don't know when to start pressing the power button. Tried like 50 times. Still don't get it.

Comment: @DarkShade You don't press anything - if the Windows bootloader fails to load Windows twice in a row, it will automatically boot to WinRE _(it will initially try to auto-fix the issue and then prompt you with the WinRE blue screen that allows you to access WinRE's command line, as well as other WinRE options)_. If Windows boots, WinRE can be auto-booted to from the log-in screen by holding down `Shift` while selecting _Restart_ from the power drop-down menu.

Comment: @JW0914 Yeah. but it just doesn't fail. however I can't restart freom login screen. tried shift + power button and just power button to make it fail on its boot but its just fast booting or a quick shutdown and then a normal startup when turning it back on. always have to hold power button to shut down (no matter if it is on booting or at logiin screen).

Comment: @JW0914 every button in dropmenu at login screen. cause it is like selecting an option from a menu (just highlighs which one I click and then nothing).

Comment: @DarkShade The power button on the login screen, not the physical power button, should have a _Restart_ option and holding down `Shift` while selecting _Restart_ will boot to WinRE _(this is well documented)_, As for the bootloader, you can force it to boot to WinRE by holding down the power button until it powers off as soon as you see the Windows bootloader logo - do this twice in a row and it will boot to WinRE _(this is well documented)_. For UEFI motherboards, it may take a few tries because Windows boots in ~8s with UEFI and an SSD.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting registry keys like this is a major problem, compounded by the fact that the machine is used for dual booting.

To repair the computer in place, run a Windows Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

You can start with the first method but that may not work in this case.

**(1) Keep Everything:** Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

**(2) Keep Data:** Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

**(3) Keep Nothing:** Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install, but still in place on the computer.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Comment: wait 'a min. I know you. U R the one who solved my python3 tkinter case. Okay but I have windows 8.1. Also can't login with password. I never did a backup (cause I did'nt had enough storage. I had kali linux, 2 ubuntu-14 and then Windows 8.1.).

Comment: You might wish to backup when you can and then upgrade the machine to Windows 10. Windows 10 works much better. That will also rebuild and fix the deleted Registry Keys.

Comment: Brother, I have 3.7 Gb ram WIN 10 won't be fast enough for me though it has some extra features. Tested it with another lap that had windows 7 ultimate upgraded it does not take 15 min to boot while windows 7 ultimate took 8 min.

Comment: @DarkShade Win10's smart installer will attenuate the install to the hardware specs available and will run better than Win 8.1, however, in general, Windows won't run well with <8GB RAM and less than a 4C CPU due to the number of services it relies upon. Clean install startup times shouldn't exceed ~60s _(upgraded install is not recommended due to incompatible drivers that are not possible to efficiently remove from `%WinDir%` due to being renamed `oem##.inf` upon install)_. Win10 will auto-install all drivers, except OEM CPU-related ones _(Chipset, IMEI, etc.)_ via Windows Update